# R Shiny: Calculate duplicate outputs only once

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to replicate a single output (e.g date/time) across multiple `tabPanel`s. However, despite their being derived from the same reactive function, there is a brief calculation between tabs resulting in a delay.

In other words, once the output is calculated once, I would like it to be rendered across all tabs without any delay.

I imagine `reactiveValues` or an `observe` function may help, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Please see the example below.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
 "Example",tabPanel("Tab_1",
                    textOutput("date_1")),tabPanel("Tab_2",textOutput("date_2"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  date = reactive({
    Sys.time()
    })
  
  output$date_2 = 
  output$date_1 = renderText(date())
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you.

Comment: How much time delay.  I couldn't find any difference in time.  Did you meant `output$date_2 = renderText(date())`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I see the exact same Sys.time on both tabs. Shiny doesn't draw tabs that aren't currently visible. So it won't render the second tab till you click on the second tab, but it doesn't regenerate the reactive data.

Comment: Thanks, @akrun.  Happy with the current ```output$date_2 = 
  output$date_1 = renderText(date())``` as both outputs are identical. With this example the time delay only manifests as a "flicker". However, in my actual app there is a bit more of a delay.

Comment: Thanks, @MrFlick. I think this gets to the heart of the question. As I am not recalculating the reactive data (it renders the exact same time as intended), is there no way to have ```output$date_2``` already calculated prior to clicking on tab_2?

Comment: Maybe you want `suspendWhenHidden=FALSE`. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50684756/optimizing-shiny-performance-with-tabs-and-suspendwhenhidden-false